# MySQL Procedure with IN date fails

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

First time poster really appreciate any assistance.

I am completely stuck on an issue with MySQL stored procedures and completely green to them.

Here is the procedure as it is currently written, MySQL accepts it without any issue so unless there is a syntax error, the procedure is written correctly.

However when I call the procedure 
`call test (2011-04-01, 2011-04-07);`
 no results are returned, yet the select statement works just fine.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN `@StartDate` date,IN `@EndDate` date)

BEGIN

SELECT aux1, aux2, aux3, aux4, date, id, type,
    CASE
        WHEN results = 'pass' THEN '1'
        WHEN results = 'fail' THEN '0'
        ELSE '-1'
    END AS CertStatus,
    CASE
        WHEN results = 'pass' THEN '1'
        WHEN results = 'fail' THEN '0'
        ELSE '-1'
    END AS TestStatus,
    CASE
        WHEN results = 'pass' THEN '1'
        WHEN results = 'fail' THEN '0'
        ELSE '-1'
    END AS TestStatus,
    CASE
        WHEN results = 'pass' THEN '1'
        WHEN results = 'fail' THEN '0'
        ELSE '-1'
    END AS TestStatus
from completed
WHERE date >= '@StartDate' and date <= '@EndDate';
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick tidy up - i'll leave it to '@You' to SPOT the 'differences' and there are more than '1'

```
delimiter ;

drop procedure if exists list_test_status;

delimiter #

create procedure list_test_status
(
in p_start_date date,
in p_end_date date
)
begin

select aux1, aux2, aux3, aux4, date, id, type,
case
    when results = 'pass' then 1
    when results = 'fail' then 0
    else -1
end as CertStatus,
case
    when results = 'pass' then 1
    when results = 'fail' then 0
    else -1
end as TestStatus,
case
    when results = 'pass' then 1
    when results = 'fail' then 0
    else -1
end as TestStatus,
case
    when results = 'pass' then 1
    when results = 'fail' then 0
    else -1
end as TestStatus
from 
 completed
where 
 date >= p_start_date and date <= p_end_date;

end#

delimiter ;

call list_test_status(curdate() - interval 1 month, curdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates must be passed within quotes

```
call test ('2011-04-01', '2011-04-07');
```

edit. Why do you call test if your stored procedure is named `NewProc` ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately that still does not return any results.

Comment: Have you tried to run the query without the stored procedure using the same two dates? Are you sure that there are records within that range? Moreover try to remove quotes around @StartDate and @EndDate

Comment: I don't even understand the meaning of all those cases. I didn't note them before. You apply them always to the same values and repeat them a lot of times. This is useless.

Comment: Nick,  the cases are used in other fields, I did a quick cut and paste  to hide actual field names.  My intent was the maintain the overall integrity of the query in the event it was part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote the variables, otherwise it is an invalid date (the string '@xxx' cannot convert to a date).
Don't backtick the parameters
You are also returning TestStatus 3 times... crazy stuff!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN StartDate date,IN EndDate date)
BEGIN

SELECT aux1, aux2, aux3, aux4, date, id, type,
    CASE
        WHEN results = 'pass' THEN '1'
        WHEN results = 'fail' THEN '0'
        ELSE '-1'
    END AS CertStatus,
    @cache := CASE
        WHEN results = 'pass' THEN '1'
        WHEN results = 'fail' THEN '0'
        ELSE '-1'
    END AS TestStatus,
    @cache AS TestStatus, # 2nd time ?
    @cache AS TestStatus  # 3rd time ??
from completed
WHERE date >= StartDate and date <= EndDate;
END;
```